# python type() and isinstance() don't recognize instance of class

Tags: python, isinstance

`isinstance(object, classinfo)` doesn't recognize an instance of a class.

I printed `type(object)` and the class itself to verify that they were the same types. They both printed the exact same thing however when I tried `type(object) == class` it returned `False`.

here is the code for the class:

```py
class Convolute(object):
    def __init__(self, channels, filter_shape, pool_shape, pool_type, stride_length=1):
        self.channels = channels
        self.filter_shape = filter_shape
        self.filters = [np.random.randn(filter_shape[0], filter_shape[1]) for i in range(channels)]
        self.biases = [random.random() for i in range (channels)]
        self.stride_length = stride_length
        self.pool_shape = pool_shape
        self.pool_type = pool_type
```

here is the instance of the class:

```py
con1 = n.Convolute(3, (4, 4), (4, 4), 0)
```

here is the output in the python shell when I tried to verify they were the same type:

```py
>>> import network as n
>>> con1 = n.Convolute(3, (4, 4), (4, 4), 0)
>>> type(con1)
<class 'network.Convolute'>
>>> n.Convolute
<class 'network.Convolute'>
>>> type(con1) == n.Convolute
False
>>> isinstance(con1, n.Convolute)
False
```

Since the output of `type(con1)` and `n.Convolute` seem to be identical I expected that `isinstance()` and `type(con1) == n.Convolute` would return `True` but they return `False'. I am honestly beyond confused please help.

--EDIT--

`type(con1).__name__ == n.Convolute.__name__` returns `True` but I still do not know why nothing else works

The problem is also inside of the file that I import from, I just also ran into the same problem in the file itself not just when I imported it. Here is the code inside the program:

```py
class Network(object):

    #params for class are layers described by class e.g. ConvolutionalNetwork([Input([...]), Convolute([...]), Flatten(), Dense([...]), (Dense[...]]) 
    #__init__ and setflattensize functions initilize network structures
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers
        self.channels = [layers[0].channels]
        self.shapes = [layers[0].shape]
        for layer, index in zip(layers, range(len(layers))):
            if isinstance(layer, Flatten):
                self.setflattensize(layer, index)
            if isinstance(layer, Dense):
                layer.weights = np.random.randn(self.layers[index-1].size, layer.size) 
            #get list of channels and shapes/sizes that correspond with each layer
            if index>0:
                if self.channels[-1]*layer.channels == 0:
                    self.channels.append(1)
                else:
                    self.channels.append(self.channels[-1]*layer.channels)
                if isinstance(layer, Convolute):
                    self.shapes.append(((self.shapes[-1][0]-layer.filter_shape[0]+1)/layer.pool_shape[0], (self.shapes[-1][1]-layer.filter_shape[1]+1)/layer.pool_shape[1]))
                else:
                    self.shapes.append(layer.size)
```

the `if isinstance(layer, Convolute):` returns `False` instead of `True`. This is the problem that is explained more in depth earlier.

runable code that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/Ecart33/MachineLearning/blob/master/neural_net/network_debug.py

Comment: That's odd. Compare with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549814

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue using relatively simple classes, both `isinstance` and `type(inst)==cls` return `True`, whether imported or constructed in `__main__`

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Are you doing something funny with your imports (e.g. mangling `sys.path` somewhere)? If so, you could end up with *two independent types* with the same name, imported from different copies of the same module.

Comment: @DanielPryden I think you might be on to something, if I import two separate instances of a module containing that class, `import something as n; import something_else as s` the instantiate that class using `c = n.Convolute`, it fails the check for `isinstance(c, s.Convolute)`

Comment: Just what Daniel Pryden says - that's actually the very typical symptom of duplicate imports. Check your `sys.path` and `sys.modules`. The whole thing is explained here: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap

Comment: @C.Nivs : what Daniel mentions is actually not related to "import XXX as YYY" which only binds two names to the same module instance (and doesn't cause any identity issue). Check the link I posted for a more in-depth explanation of the double-import gotcha (which creates two distinct modules _instances_ from the same source file)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers checking it out now, cheers

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the problem itself is also in the python file I import from not only after I import it in the shell. I'll edit the question to add this as well.

Comment: At this point, all we can do is *guess* until you provide a [mcve] which we can actually *run* to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @DanielPryden this code is runable and demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/Ecart33/MachineLearning/blob/master/neural_net/network_debug.py

Comment: @ecart33 the code snippet you posted is NOT a proper MCVE - it's not minimal (useless deps on 3rd part packages and obviously useless code), and it's not complete (there are only class definitions, when obviously some code is needed to use those classes).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers and others sorry about that I added code in to make it run and it does seem to be a problem with the imports. I don't know why there is a problem since I have been doing similar things with isinstance() that have worked perfectly fine but I will look into it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read the link I posted and _check your sys.path and sys.modules_.